# How to disable all notification sounds and banner alerts but allow notifications on lockscreen?

Tags: iphone, ios, notifications

In iOS 15 how can I stop all notification noises and stop banner alerts and other types of notification pop-up from ever appearing while I am using the phone, but allow notifications to pile up on the lockscreen so that when I turn my phone on I can see a list of all the notifications that have accumulated since I turned it off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option could be scheduling a custom Focus Mode (a variant of Don't Disturb).

- You can define who(exceptions) you want to get notified about if they call (only if you want to — don't add anyone for the behaviour you want based on your question)
- Mass enable or disable apps when the mode is turned on.
- Add a schedule when it kicks in and ends. (if you make it 00:00 to 00:00, I think it will always be on.)

All notifications will only pile up on the lockscreen. Additionally, if you don't want to see the app bubbles you can individually turn them off.

This [link](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT212608) could useful.

Steps:

1. Settings --> Focus --> Click the (+) in the top right -->  Custom -->  Give it a name and icon.
2. Remove everyone to get previous dnd behaviour --> Allow/Allow None
3. Remove all apps --> Allow/Allow None
4. Done
5. Home Screen --> Hide Notification Badges. (Since you only want it on Lock Screen)
6. Lockscreen --> (You can dim Lock Screen), Silenced Notification -->"Show on Lock Screen".
7. Add Schedule or Automation --> Time --> Schedule --> From 00:00 to 00:00. --> Tap every day to select.
8. Done.

Comment: How do I do this? Should I add or remove everyone? How do I make a focus for my phone only?

Comment: @theonlygusti I modified my answer, please let me know if that works the way you want it.